# Excel VBA: Automatically insert sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is not so much a code specific question and more a question around if Excel/VBA is capable of this and what the best method to take is to achieve it.

I have a table set up and the first 2 columns are drop down boxes (this is the database sheet). The drop down selections are pulled from another sheet where the user can enter values (so the drop down is reliant on this sheet for it's data), this is called the input sheet.

I'd like to make it so every unique value in the drop down database automatically inserts a new sheet which populates all the data that is linked to that drop down (so the entire row)

I've made an image to describe the concept

[image: example]

Is this something that is possible in Excel and VBA?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes sure it's possible, have a look at the `Worksheet_Change` under your input sheet. Loop through it's range, and delete/insert sheets when car makes are deleted/entered.

Comment: Where can I find the command to insert sheet?